# Key combination to increase text selection to the opposite side

Tags: windows, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, text-editors

Consider I have the following text:

> Among other things I like programming quite a lot

I then select "like" with a mouse:

> Among other things I [like] programming quite a lot"

...and then I use <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>-></kbd> to select "programming":

> Among other things I [like programming] quite a lot"

Is there any key combination I can use in this position to increase the selection to include "I "?

I don't want to navigate and then re-select, I want to increase the text already selected to include two characters to the left.

Answer (score 1):

What can help here is simple plugin: it must from selecton `test block|` (
`|` is caret) make selectiion `|test block`.

It's easy to make: in Sublime Text (python), SynWrite (python). Ask at forums of them.

Comment: I was wondering if there is something default and OS-level, but thank you for suggestion.

Comment: I know many apps, don't know default thing